# Invalid column name 'total_counted'

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I'm querying the bin table to get the total active bins, total counted bins and calculate the percent of bins counted.  Here's my query:

```
SELECT bin.location_id
,SUM(CASE WHEN bin.delete_flag = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_active
,SUM(CASE WHEN bin.date_last_counted > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_counted
--,(total_counted / total_active) as pct_counted

From bin 
Group by bin.location_id
Order by bin.location_id
```

When I try to use the code to create my pct_counted, it tells me "invalid column name" for both of the columns I'm using to calculate that value.  Data looks like below.

```
location_id     total_active    total_counted
2               11502           484
6               2281            108
15              1772            253
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can't reuse an alias, repeat the calculation instead: `SUM(CASE WHEN bin.date_last_counted > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN bin.delete_flag = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`. But this results in INTEGER calculation, you might need to add `1.0 * SUM(...` to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat the expressions (or use a subquery or CTE).  I would recommend:

```
SELECT bin.location_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN bin.delete_flag = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_active,
       SUM(CASE WHEN bin.date_last_counted > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_counted
       (SUM(CASE WHEN bin.date_last_counted > 0 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) /
        SUM(CASE WHEN bin.delete_flag = 'N' THEN 1 END)
       ) AS as pct_counted
FROM bin 
GROUP BY bin.location_id
ORDER BY bin.location_id;
```

Note that I removed the `ELSE` clause for the second expression.  This avoids divide-by-zero.  The `1.0` also ensures decimal division even if your database does integer division.

Answer (score 0):

I would format the sub-query this way:

```
   Select
         a.location_id
        total_counted/total_active as pct_counted
        from(select
        bin.location_id
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN bin.delete_flag = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_active
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN bin.date_last_counted > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_counted
        
        From bin 
        Group by bin.location_id
        Order by bin.location_id) a
```